# Python ordering when reading/printing a Sorted(items)

Tags: python, python-3.x, glob

Say I have images of dogs in a directory with its name and numbering as:

```
dog 1.jpg
dog 2.jpg
dog 3.jpg
.
.
dog 11.jpg
dog 12.jpg
```

when I perform `sorted(glob.glob('that_dir/*jpg'))` and `print`, it returns:

```
dog 1.jpg
dog 10.jpg
dog 11.jpg
dog 12.jpg
.
.
dog 8.jpg
dog 9.jpg
```

is there a way to make it return in order of `dog 1.jpg, dog 2.jpg .. dog 12.jpg` in this case?
or is it wiser to avoid this numbering method altogether and use something like leading zeros instead?

Comment: Use sorted(glob.glob('that_dir/*jpg'), key = lambda x: int(x[4:].split('.')[0]))

Comment: I think what you're looking for is called a "natural sort" - if you search on that term you should find lots.  But adding leading zeros is the quick and easy solution.

Comment: Hey, thanks Mark! that's exactly it! I've never heard of that term before, so this is something new for me!

Answer (score 1):

One way using `distutils.version.LooseVersion`:

```
from distutils.version import LooseVersion

l = ['dog 12.jpg', 'dog 1.jpg', 'dog 11.jpg', 
     'dog 2.jpg', 'dog 3.jpg', 'dog 10.jpg']

sorted(l, key=LooseVersion)
```

Output:

```
['dog 1.jpg',
 'dog 2.jpg',
 'dog 3.jpg',
 'dog 10.jpg',
 'dog 11.jpg',
 'dog 12.jpg']
```